# No devuelve resultado exec_command con paramiko en python

Tags: python, ssh

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexion usando paramiko en python desde windows. Uso Jupyter para realizar la conexion:

```
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='ipServidor',username='USR',password='pass')

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('pwd')
```

Hasta aquí todo me corre aparentemente bien 
sin embargo al momento de querer obtener el resultado jupyter se queda sin avanzar

```
print(stdout.readlines())
```

si ejecuto el comando

```
print(stdout)
```

obtengo esta respuesta

```
paramiko.ChannelFile from paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 in-buffer=52  paramiko.
Transport at 0x4b8ed68 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

A mi solía darme problemas el readlines así que recurrí a esto:

```
stdout_read = stdout.read().split("\\n")
```